# Using c# Facebook SDK to verify installs though Facebook ads

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-c#-sdk

I am currently trying to make a way of verifying installs of my Windows Phone 8.1 application that have been generated through ads in Facebook. You can do this very easily for iOS and Android by downloading the respective SDKs and adding essentially one line of code to your project. See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads)

Does anyone know of a way of creating this functionality for Windows Phone 8.1? I am trying to analyze the C# Facebook SDK downloadable from Nuget [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/facebook) but finding it difficult to imagine how I would actually implement this.

Thank you